# Redirect inside a component in React with react-router 3

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How to do a route redirect in React component with react router 3 ?

If I user a 'guard' component like this:

```
const GuardContainer = (props) => {

    const {ok} = isOk(props)

    if (!ok) {
        // Redirect here  to /not-ok      
        return null
    }

    return <WrappedComponent {...props}/>
}
```

then React complains about changing state with

> Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within
>   `render` or another component's constructor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In React Router V4 there is a `<Redirect />` component that allows you to render and it will navigate to the target. You can probably make your own in V3 using `browserHistory`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

class Redirect extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    browserHistory.push(this.props.to);
  }

  render() {
    return <div />
  }

}

export default Redirect;
```

Then render it with `to="/not-ok"`

```
if (!ok) {
  return <Redirect to="/not-ok" />;
}
```

Give this a try or something similar to it.

Comment: Dude - you just helped me out so much. I had been trying to find a solution for this for a long time. Thank you man

Answer (score 0):

Decision from react-router v3:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

    export default function GuardContainer(props) {
        const {ok} = isOk(props);

        if (!ok) {
            // Redirect here  to /not-ok
            browserHistory.push('/not-ok');
        }

        return <WrappedComponent {...props} />
    }
```